# Noob needs help. How to complete Ubuntu download

Tags: system-installation

I'm trying to get linux setup on my PC so I can use python packages unavailable on windows. When I complete the 64 bit download and run the program a Power2Go window comes up with a bunch of files in the left panel. I'm not sure where to go from here, and from what I'm reading on the ubuntu website I somehow need to download from DVD or USB?

Not really sure what to do, but if someone could clarify would definitely appreciate the help.

Comment: There are very detailed instructions on howto create an Ubuntu [DVD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows) or [USB](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows). Please review, and follow.

Answer (score 2):

/*although I have listed all the steps below , but **I recommend you to backup your full data in your  windows/mac to a pendrive/(by data I mean personal stuff,important files,etc and not windows backup:))..**
I recommend watching a youtube video at step 3 as I have written below is a highly abstracted(by this I mean , I have assumed many things ) list and I don't take any responsibility if you loose any data...and No one else will ... So it is EXTREMELY IMPORTANT THAT YOU BACKUP YOUR DATA TO AN EXTERNAL HARDDRIVE,DVD,USB so it is safe no matter what happens'(it has happened with me..I highly regret that moment , trust me)..upvote this answer if you have installed , wasted much of my time to write this long answer */

1. download ubuntu from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you/?version=14.04.4&architecture=amd64

   2. download universal usb installer http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/ and select ubuntu from list, browse to the folder where you have the iso installed, and click on next ...
   3. restart your pc and press f12 (based on which system you are using , google "how to go to boot menu  in company_name model_name"   eg: how to go to boot menu in dell 5547)
   4. select your pendrive
   5. next, next , next selecting appropriate choices..
   6. choose whether you want to install ubuntu with windows or you just want to install ubuntu removing all windows stuff...
   7. next...
   8. restart